# Is there a possibility to use the ring-points from displacement renderer in qgis for map-tips?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, maptips

I've got as "layer 1" a point data-set and as "layer 2" a point-dataset (with the identical geometries of layer 1) with a varying number of photos (=identical points) to every point of layer 1.

Is there a possibility to get all photos from the overlapping (photo-)points within a map-tip ? (The QGIS map-tip seems to show only the first object/photo of the overlapping objects.)

The displacement-renderer point-symbols on the ring do not show map-tips - only the central point.

I think there may be two different approaches:

1) It would be nice to get map-tips from the displaced symbols *(I've looked up the QgsPointDisplacementRenderer Class Reference API docs but I didn't get a hint how to use it regarding my question)* or

2) Is there a inside map-tips usable html expression which can be used to deal with this task (showing a list of photos from a PostgreSQL-database created photo-path-array by group-function) ?